# jQuery not working on the forwarded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am testing some jQuery. I wrote a simple jsp page which on submit uses jQuery and returns the result

The code is as follows:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
       $("#hide2").click(function()
       {
           $("#result2").hide();    
       });   
     ///////////////////////        
     //some jquery code (running fine)
      /////////////////////
        });     // enable ..show ..hide 

       $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#form').submit(function() {

    var number = $('#number').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "test5.jsp",
        data:       "number=" + number,
        success:    
                   function(msg) 
                    {
                          $("#result2").html("<h3>" + msg + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
return false;
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
Enter number:
    <input id="number" type="text" name="numb" disabled/>
    <input id="enable" type="button" value="Enable">
    <input id="show" type="button" value="show">
     <input id="hide" type="button" value="hide">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate Square Root"    name="submit"/>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
</body>
```

On entering the value and submitting the request goes to `test5.jsp`

```
<%
 //java code (running fine)  
%>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>

</script> 
</head>
<body>
   <br><br> 
    <button id="hide2" value="Hide">Hide</button> --> <span id="result2">hide this</span>
</body> 
</html>
```

Now I want to apply jQuery on the hide button and I am unable to do so. In short I want to apply jQuery to the elements of `test5.jsp`

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: hard to ubnderstand what you want , you want to hide some button on success callback ? simple $('#result').hide(); in success callback

Comment: actually i want to apply jquery to the elements of the success page ie test5.jsp , the page called after submitting

Comment: its an ajax call to test5.jsp , so you want to apply some html changes with jquery on response right ?

Comment: yes exactly i want to do this .. and i want to make changes on the button ... with id `hide2`

Answer (score 0):

Ok fine , so for changing the `html`(Response) from ajax in success callback , you need to do something like below,

in your success callback ,
success:

```
 function(msg) 
 {
   //...... rest of your code
   $(msg).find("#hide2").hide();  //Hides #hide2 button from msg response

 }
```

Comment: i have added some images ...now it will be easy to understand

Comment: i used it ..it is not working ... i want to hide the text by clicking on the hide button

Comment: test4.jsp making a call to test5.jsp , result2 id is present in both pages huh ?